# Enabling visibility to primefaces panel display

Tags: html, css, primefaces, visibility

I'm new to primefaces, so I probably did a newbie mistake, but I simply can't google find my answer.
I'm trying to make a hidden panel show after I click on the checkbox, but it doesn't show.

My html looks as follows:

```
<br></br> Choose one <br></br><br></br>
```

```
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="$(‘#:testid’).css(‘display’,’visible’);" >                
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <h:outputText value=" click " />      

</h:panelGrid>

<p:panel id="testid" header="TESTHDR" style="display:none"  >
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">

    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{selectBooleanView.mTest}">         
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>        

    <h:outputText value=" test " /> 

    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

The problem is that my testid panel doesn't show after I click on the checkbox. 
I'm probably doing the checkbox action listener wrong, but I honestly can't see the problem myself.

Answer (score 1):

change display visible to display block like this because display visible does not exist in css.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="$(‘#:testid’).css(‘display’,’block’);" >
```

I think thats it if youre code works fine.

Comment: Well, removing style="display:none" from the panel shows it the way i want it to appear after clicking the checkbox, so i presume the code works fine.
Unfortunately, changing display to block didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Prime faces mangles IDs similar to ASP.NET. Both ensure that the ID is unique across the page so you get something like id="base_container_child_container_your_control_id"

You should find the way to "unmangle" it. Again in .NET you have control.ClientID which you can get from the server. Not sure about PF equivalent.

Anyhow, the solution would be to add name attribute and use
$('input[name=your-id]') // matches exactly 'your-id'
$('input[name^=your-id]') // matches those that begin with 'your-id' if you have group of them

OR use [like selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
id*='value'